How can I get the expected results when I run numpy.random.randint?
I'm writing a part about numpy while listening to a Python lecture. The numpy function does not output as it appears in the lecture, that is, as intended.
This is the code:
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0, 20, size = (5, 6))
print(x)

The result I expected(My lecture):
[[ 3  9  4 10  9  2]
 [ 6  4  7 15  1 10]
 [11  2  4  7  1 16]
 [11 18 18 10 10  4]
 [17  1  6 11 10 13]]

This is the result I get:
[[ 1 12 12 16 12 16]
 [14  9 14  8 13 13]
 [ 9 17  8  9  4 17]
 [ 4 13 16 18 12  2]
 [ 6 19 15 13  4 11]]

Please note that my code did not produce the expected result. What causes this difference? Is it related to the number of executions of colab?
THE MOST IMPORTANT QUESTION:
And how do I get the expected result?
I can't understand at all that the results are different because I entered the same code.

Surely the function name gives you a clue.  It's selecting RANDOM NUMBERS.  It's quite possible for different operating systems to use different seeds.

@Tim Roberts
Even if this generates random numbers, I learned that computer code is a function, so the same input should produce the same output. The same input should result in the same random number. Therefore, there must be some error.

@Tim Roberts Also, it is certain that there is a way to get the expected results on the computer. It is showing in the lecture I took.

I learned that computer code is a function, so the same input should produce the same output - you learned wrong.  Imagine a function that shows the current date in milliseconds - would this always show the same number?

@Scary Wombat
Is the Wikipedia information that says random values can only be obtained from a quantum random number generator incorrect? If this is true, does it mean that Colab being connected to the internet allows external values to enter my code?

You are fretting about the most trivial of topics.  If you want to use exactly the same data, then type those 30 numbers by hand, but the overall lessons is "don't worry about this".

@Tim Roberts
It is not a clear answer to this problem. I would like to hear a detailed explanation of the phenomenon. This question is also related to the inverse function of the random.randint function.

It's not a phenomenon.  It's a random number generator.  The random numbers you get depend on where you start in the sequence.  There IS no "inverse" function for random.randint.

This question is similar to: Consistently create same random numpy array. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The numpy.random functions are intended to generate random numbers (well, actually, they are pseudorandom). What that means for you is that every time you run your code, np.random.randint will generate a new random sequence. This explains why your results are different from the results from the lecture you're watching. (Run your code again and you will see you get different numbers than the ones you shared in this post.)
There is something called a "seed" that you can provide to the random number generator to then produce consistent and reproducible random numbers. Since you are not providing a seed, you will get new random numbers each time you run your code. If you are interested, I've included an example with a seed below (using the newer random generator interface of Python). If you run the code you should get the exact same numbers as I show here.
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
a = rng.integers(0, 20, size=(5,6))
print(a)

Output:
[[ 1 15 13  8  8 17]
 [ 1 13  4  1 10 19]
 [14 15 14 15 10  2]
 [16  9 10  7  3 18]
 [15 12  8 16 10  8]]

In my code, 42 is the seed. No matter how many times you run the code you will get the same 30 numbers in that order. If you were to delete 42 (and just have rng = np.random.default_rng()), every time you run the code you will get a new sequence of 30 random numbers (it is possible to get the same sequence more than once, but the chances of that are very low).

Oh! In that case, what is the process for obtaining a seed number that will give me the desired outcome?

@codebetatester Unfortunately, since the lecture did not use a seed you cannot reproduce their exact results (numpy will internally seed using some other method). If you need the same array to compare later operations, you will have to manually create that array yourself.

I see, if you're sure that's not possible,
Does it mean that there is no such method in the documents related to numpy?
And I want to know if it's technically proved impossible or theoretically proved impossible.

Also, what materials should I study to understand this in more detail?

Read some of the Numpy random documentation (I linked to it in my answer). The question you need to figure out is how much you need to understand the underlying random number generator code. For most people it's unnecessary. Just know the basics: the module is intended to generate random numbers (there are various functions for generating uniform distributions, random integers, gaussian distributions, etc) and to get reproducible random numbers you need to provide a seed.

For most people it's unnecessary.  - but I need it. I'd really appreciate it if you could let me know...please

I'm not sure what about random number generation you're trying to understand. If it's numpy random number generation then I gave you that link. If it's random number generators in general, then look at the citations on the Wikipedia page and see what they say about them. It's a very broad topic. Random number generators in numpy are probably not cryptographically safe (I might be wrong about that), so you can get into a whole other world if you're interested in cryptographically secure random number generators (there's a Wikipedia page about that as well).

To simplify the problem, I want to know the inverse function of the random.randint function. I want to know if it is a multivariate function or a univariate function.

In other words, what I want is to reverse-calculate the seed or adjust the number of executions to achieve the desired result.

You can't. That's the point of a random number generator.
